# C++ Text File, Chinese characters

Tags: c++, internationalization, rtf, cjk

I have a C++ project which is supposed to add `<item>` to the beginning of every line and `</item >` to the end of every line. This works fine with normal English text, but I have a Chinese text file I would like to do this to, but it does not work. I normally use .txt files, but for this I have to use .rtf to save the Chinese text.  After I run my code, it becomes gibberish. Here's an example.

> {\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\adeff31507\deff0\stshfdbch31506\stshfloch31506\stshfhich31506\stshfbi31507\deflang1033\deflangfe1033\themelang1033\themelangfe0\themelangcs0{\fonttbl{\f2\fbidi
>   \fmodern\fcharset0\fprq1{*\panose
>   02070309020205020404}Courier
>   New;}

Code:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    string lineT, newlineT;

    in.open("rawquote.rtf");
    if(in.fail())
       exit(1);
    out.open("itemisedQuote.rtf");
    do
    {
        getline(in,lineT,'\n');
        newlineT += "<item>";
        newlineT += lineT;
        newlineT += "</item>";
        if (lineT.length() >5)
        {
            out<<newlineT<<'\n';
        }
        newlineT = "";
        lineT = "";
    } while(!in.eof());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: View the rawquote.rtf input file in a text-only mode to see what it really contains.

Comment: Use backticks to escape code, like this: ``<item>``

Comment: Is the RTF requirement coming from a customer, or your own requirement because you were having problems with a plain text document? There is no reason you cannot output Chinese characters into a text document as long as you use the correct encoding.

Comment: Sidenote: Use &lt; in the question's source so you don't have to artificially add spaces and then note they shouldn't be there.

Comment: I don't know RTF syntax, but I suspect it has ways of representing lines which getline (which only uses \n characters) doesn't know, thus you would be (even after fixing the !eof misuse) inserting text incorrectly.  If that isn't the issue and the file doesn't use an ASCII-compatible character set (such as UTF-8), handling encoding is the next thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), which makes sense as you say this is an rtf file.

Basically, if you dump that file when you open, you'll see it looks like that...

Also, you should revisit your loop

```
std::string line;
while(getline(in, line, '\n'))
{
  // do stuff here, the above check correctly that you have indeed read in a line!
  out << "<item>" << line << "</item>" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't read the RTF code the same way as plain text as you'll just ignore format tags, etc. and might just break the code.

Try to save your chinese text as a text file using UTF-8 (without BOM) and your code should work. However this might fail if some other UTF-8 encoded character contains essentially a line break (not sure about this part right now), so you should try to do real UTF-8 conversion and read the file using wide chars instead of regular chars (as Chan suggested), which is a little bit tricky using C++.

Comment: Any UTF-8 encoded character cannot contain an ASCII character unless it is that exact character.  Remember ASCII is a 7-bit encoding and thus always has the 8th bit unset.  Any non-ASCII character in UTF-8 always has the 8th bit set in the first byte and any continuation byte.  This property is one of the things that makes UTF-8 so attractive, and it is not true for some other encodings, such as UTF-16.

Comment: You are right that if the file is UTF-8 (with or without the nonstandard "UTF-8 BOM"), then fixing the file handling (i.e. !eof) is enough to have this code work.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a miracle that this works for non-Chinese text.  "\n" is not the line separator in RTF, "\par" is.  The odds that more damage is done to the RTF header are certainly greater for Chinese.

C++ is not the best language to tackle this.  It is a trivial 5 minute program in C# as long as the file doesn't get too large:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;   // Add reference

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.LoadFile(args[0], RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        var lines = rtb.Lines;
        for (int ix = 0; ix < lines.Length; ++ix) {
            lines[ix] = "<item>" + lines[ix] + "</item>";
        }
        rtb.Lines = lines;
        rtb.SaveFile(args[0], RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    }
}
```

If C++ is a hard requirement then you'll have to find an RTF parser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 'wchar' for string instead of 'regular char'.

Comment: I think you mean wchar_t instead of wchar, but this is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the objective of this code, your solution is not going to work. A line break in an RTF document does not correspond to a line break in the visible text.

If you can't just use plain text (Chinese characters are not a problem with a valid encoding), take a look at the [RTF spec](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=DD422B8D-FF06-4207-B476-6B5396A18A2B&displaylang=en). You'll discover that it is a nightmare. So you're best bet is probably a third-party library that can parse RTF and read it "line" by "line." I have never looked for such a library, so do not have any suggestions off the top of my head, but I'm sure they are out there.